# how to integrate angularjs with asp.net web api

Tags: c#, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am new in angularjs and asp.net. I've searched a lot but did not get proper answer and more confused.

my problems are:

1) how to integrate angularjs application integrate with asp.net MVC web API using SQL server.

2) I got the solution for two projects like one is client second is a server so now first I starts server project as the startup project and then client project starts as the startup project and then performs API operation so my question is:

i) what happened when upload it to a global server.
ii) will I add both of projects one by one on server (server and client)?

my desire is to make it in one project and angular should be in html due to performance purpose so don't want to shifting as **cshtml** and also want some cshtml page for admin panel like (product upload etc)
I am looking for best approach kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear Zeeshan it's not complicated.
As you mentioned **angularjs** manager client side of your project with MVC pattern and ASP.net web API makes your server side services as RESTFul. If you want develop both of server and client side it's up to you but Somehow you will get involved with both of them. In production you will have no problem with these, you must just deploy **Asp.Net** and **angularjs** play will play his role as a simple JavaScript library.

You can use [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/build-a-single-page-application-spa-with-aspnet-web-api-and-angularjs) as a sample.

Comment: yes thank you for your response but still not able to send data from angular html form to database using API

Comment: please put some your client and server side codes there, I'll help you.

Comment: can you contact on Teamviewer because of no of files of code.

Comment: ID and password?